# How to sort the query results?

Tags: 8, database

In my task I need to display the results based on "the newest first". I perform a query:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'node');
$query->innerJoin('node__field_ils_apps', 'app', 'app.entity_id = node.nid AND app.field_ils_apps_target_id = '.$node->id());
$query->addField('app', 'entity_id', 'nid');
$query->groupBy('app.entity_id');

$query->orderBy('created', 'DESC');
$query->execute();
```

But it returns me an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
```

Could you please tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: This is an SQL question rather than Drupal - you need to add selected columns to the group by clause

Comment: Maybe you can add the SQL that you want to translate to Drupal's DB layer. I cant see what you're trying to do.

Comment: It says exactly what you need to do, you need to add created column also into the grouping clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

$connection = Database::getConnection();
  //- Step one get all referenced nids
  $query = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'nfd')
    ->fields('nfd', ['nid', 'created']);
   $query->innerJoin('node__field_ils_apps', 'app', 'nfd.nid = app.entity_id');
  $query->orderBy('created', 'DESC');
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```